# Include a PHP File Which Contains PHP Code

Tags: php, php-include

In my reader file, I check for $_GET and read a record from database.

I've a contact information schema. Saved in "contact.php" file. But in database, I just used "[contact]" as text.

So here is what I do for calling that contact.php file:

```
$contactinfo = file_get_contents('contact.php');
$mydata = str_replace("[contact]", $contactinfo, $mydata);
return html_entity_decode($mydata);
```

This works perfect. Because my "contact.php" file ONLY CONTAINS HTML.

Here is my problem. I've another file, "contactform.php". This form contains HTML and a PHP method for filling a select input with cities. I mean, my "contactform.php" file is like that:

```
<form>
Name: <input name bla bla>
Email: <input email bla bla>
City: <?php getcities(); ?>
<input submit bla bla>
</form>
```

I use exact same method. But I only get:

```
<form>
Name: <input name bla bla>
Email: <input email bla bla>
City: <!-- <?php getcities(); ?> -->
<input submit bla bla>
</form>
```

My PHP part converts to comment line. Other parts works fine. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you are approaching a problem in the wrong way. Answering this would make it worse.

Comment: so show me the right way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can single the line out with some kind of regex, [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need change logic and replace file_get_contents to [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) OR [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) OR require_once OR include_once.

You need change your code

```
ob_start( );
require('contact.php');
$contactinfo = ob_get_clean( );
$mydata = str_replace("[contact]", $contactinfo, $mydata);
return html_entity_decode($mydata);
```

or if use ob_get_contents

```
ob_start();
echo "You main script, before contact ";

ob_start();
echo "contact form";
$ob_2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "and after contact";
$ob_1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "This is OB_1: ".$ob_1."\n"; //returned "This is OB_1: You main script, before contact and after contact"
echo "This is OB_2: ".$ob_2."\n"; //returned "This is OB_2: contact form"
```

Comment: how can you include a file dynamically? I'm storing a user-generated html in my database. user doesn't know php. user only need to put something like [contactform] to add a contact form in page.

Comment: please see my changes in answer

Comment: I'm already using a ob_start at top of my page (for header(location)). is that going to be a problem? also, can you get multiple files with that method?

Comment: Yes, you can call it more than once. It creates a new buffer each time. please read this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198049/can-phps-ob-start-be-called-more-then-once]. And yes  you can get multiple files with that method after ob_get_clean

Comment: But when I do this, I lose my parameters. btw these are all in the same page. ob_start() paramteres... connections.. some functions.. your answer. When I do this for 1 time, it's OK. but if I call ob_start second time in method (so 3rd time in whole page) I lose my parameters.

Comment: Try use ob_get_contents()

Comment: this does not help. I'm starting ob in a file. but calling include file from a function inside that file. the two include ob's must only stay inside that function and should not interact with ob_start which at outside

Comment: i don't see a problem, because no matter from what  place calling ob_start from file or from function . Give me access to your source code and I will try fix for you.